# Phonegap: Display/Parse XML Data by pages

Tags: html, xml, xml-parsing, cordova

I'm a newbie in Phonegap. Does anyone have any idea how I can display my XML data by page on a Phonegap app. For example, on one page, it would be a post and there will be a button to the next post like in the XML.

Below is my XML data. Is there any tutorials or so on this?

```
<post>
<new>
<picture>http://placehold.it/350x250</picture>
<name>post name 1</name>
<info>More info here. Such as post content</info>
<moreinfo>Deeper information </moreinfo>
<mix>Some info</mix>
<mixinfo>Choice of 2,3,4 Bedrooms</mixinfo>
</new>
<new>
<picture>http://placehold.it/350x250</picture>
<name>post name 2</name>
<info>Post Name 2</info>
<moreinfo>Infomation here</moreinfo>
<mix>Mix it up</mix>
<mixinfo>Information of more information</mixinfo>
</new>
</post>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All modern browsers have a built-in XML parser.

An XML parser converts an XML document into an XML DOM object - which can then be manipulated with JavaScript.

You can do this with [by your own](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_parser.asp) or with [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/).

Comment: Thanks, however, do you have any idea I can put them into each page just like post after post?

Comment: First take a look at [jQuery Mobile Multi-Page Template Structure](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/dist/demos/widgets/pages/). When you parsed your XML you can manipulate your mobile pages with [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/html/) and put the posts to the specific page.

Comment: Hmm.. I think that is a good idea but how can I link the posts by having a next and previous button?

Comment: Simply put the first post to the first page and the second to the second page and so on. Then you can use jQuery Mobile functions to jump between the pages/posts (with a button for example). Read the jQuery Mobile link in my previous comment.